# What is the runtime of toCharArray() and toString() in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, arrays

What is the performance of these?

```
BigInteger -> toString() // what is the runtime?

String -> toCharArray()  // what is the runtime?
```

Thanks.

Comment: Of what benefit is this question?

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Say n is the number of characters in the string. What is the big O for converting string into an array of size n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversion of `BigInteger` to string is `O(N^2)`, where `N` is the number of digits in the result, when the base of the internal representation does not divide the target base; when the target base is divisible by the storage base, conversion takes `O(N)`.

Consider conversion to base 10 when the internal representation is base-256. A division by ten has to happen `N` times; each time, all elements of the `BigInteger` representation get modified. The number of elements in the representation is proportional to the number of digits in the printout, so the overall conversion takes `O(N^2)`.

On the other hand, converting to hex of a big int in base-256 internal representation takes `O(N)`, because division is not necessary in this case. Each subelement can be converted in isolation from the remaining ones, and the number of sub-elements is proportional to the number of digits in the printout.

As far as `String.toCharArray()` goes, it's `O(N)`, where `N` is the number of characters in the string, because each character must be copied into the output.

Comment: Are you sure `toCharArray` is `O(N)` and not `O(1)` - aren't strings stored as character arrays anyway?

Comment: @A.R.S. Arrays in Java are mutable, while strings are not. The `toCharArray` must make a copy of length `N`, forcing the `O(N)` time complexity.

Comment: Oh, now by looking at the source I see that they do in fact copy all the characters over to a new array.

Comment: Are you sure about BigInteger.toString being `O(N)` for some radixes and O(N^2) for others? Looking at the source code, there's not a lot of difference in the execution path or loop counts for different radix values. It looks like it does synthetic division one `int` at a time, carrying forward the product and the remainder. This would make it O(N) in every case.

Comment: @TedHopp We are probably looking at different sources: the one I see [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/math/BigInteger-source.html) has the `format` method on line 1471. It has a special case for base 16 which is `O(N)`, and a case for everything else (line 1502 and on) that looks like `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Are you quite certain that `BigInteger.divide` is linear? ;)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Only when the divisor is constant :)

Comment: Judging from the copyright notice at the top, that's pretty old. Take a look [here](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/java/math/BigInteger.java.html) instead (line 2620). That's what I see in my Java 6 jdk sources.

Comment: @TedHopp I guess that the other implementation is always `O(N^2)` regardless of the base. There is one loop inside `toString`, and another one inside `divide` (it may have more than one loop, but the base is fixed, so division by a constant is linear).

Comment: see my comment, but it uses System.arrayCopy which is a native method.  I imagine it uses memcpy, which is O(N)

Answer (score 1):

The toString() method is implemented using System.arrayCopy, which happens to be a native method.

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    char result[] = new char[count];
    getChars(0, count, result, 0);
    return result;
}

public void getChars(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, char dst[], int dstBegin) {
    // bounds checking
    System.arraycopy(value, offset + srcBegin, dst, dstBegin,
         srcEnd - srcBegin);
}
```

I would imagine that the native method probably uses memcpy under the hood which is O(N), so the runtime O is dependent on the actual jvm implementation.  You might take a look at the open jdk source to check the source for this native method.